# First-order definability of structures of at least $n$ elements

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

In class, we learned that it is possible to define structures of at least $n$ elements using the following WFF $\exists^{\geq n}$:

$$\exists x_1 \ldots x_n \bigwedge_{i \not= j} \neg (x_i = x_j)$$

> Then, for any interpretation $(\mathcal A, \mathcal E^ \mathcal A)$,
>   $(\mathcal A, \mathcal E^ \mathcal A) \models \exists^{\geq n}$ iff
>   $|D_\mathcal A|$ has at least n elements.

But this statement is not quite true, is it? We make the implicit assumption that any first-order structure models equality logic.

So, a more correct statement would be

> Then, for any interpretation $(\mathcal A, \mathcal E^ \mathcal A)$, $(\mathcal A, \mathcal E^ \mathcal A) \models \exists^{\geq n}$ iff $|D_\mathcal A|$ has at least n elements, provided that $(\mathcal A, \mathcal E^ \mathcal A)$ is a model of equality logic.

Here are my two questions:

1. Is my reasoning correct? Am I missing something?
2. If so, is there another way to prove / refute the first-order definability of structures of at least $n$ elements?

**EDIT**

In above argument I make the assumption that I treat $=$ as an arbitrary predicate symbol $P$, such that $P(x, y)$ is logically equivalent with $x=y$. By convention, $P(x, y)$ of course represents equality. But if we are talking about ALL first-order structures, we need to include those where $P(x, y)$ does not represent equality.

Comment: What is your definition of "$(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{E}^\mathcal{A})$ is a model of equality logic"?

Comment: @AlexKruckman It is satisfiable by the set of axioms for equality logic:
(1) $\forall x (x = x)$ 

(2) $\forall x y (x=y \to y = x)$

(3) $\forall xyz (x=y \land y=z \to x=z)$

(4) $\forall x_1, \ldots, x_n, y_1, \ldots, y_n (x_1=y_1 \land \ldots \land x_n=y_n \to f^n (x_1, \ldots, x_n) = f^n (y_1, \ldots, y_n))$ for all function symbols $f^n$

(5) $\forall x_1, \ldots, x_n, y_1, \ldots, y_n (x_1=y_1 \land \ldots \land x_n=y_n \to P^n (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \to P^n (y_1, \ldots, y_n))$ for all predicate symbols $P^n$

Comment: For example, an interpretation where $1=3$ evaluates to true is not be a model of equality logic.

Comment: Oh really? Which of your five axioms fails when $1 = 3$?

Comment: @AlexKruckman I might butcher this one, but here we go :-) Let $f(x) = x+1$ and assume $1=3$. Observe that $f(1) = 2$ and $f(3) = 4$. Then, by axiom (4) $1=3 \to f(1) = f(3)$, which is absurd ($2$ and $4$ are not equal). Thus, $1=3$ can't be true in a model of equality logic. Putting it differently, adding the WFF $1=3$ to our theory would make our theory inconsistent.

My main point: If we treat $=$ as an arbitrary binary predicate $P$ such that $x=y \leftrightarrow P(x, y)$, then there are plenty of interpretations where $P$ does not stand for equality.

Comment: All you've shown is that in a language with the successor function $f$, if $1 = 3$, then $2 = 4$. If your language has only equality and no other function or relation symbols, then you're free to interpret equality as any equivalence relation you like. For example, I could look at the interpretation $(\mathbb{N}, \mathcal{E})$ where the $\mathcal{E}$-classes are $\{0\}, \{1,3\}, \{2\}, \{4\}, \{5\}, \dots$. This is a model of equality logic. If you have other function and relation symbols in the language, there are more constraints...

Comment: ...But for example I could look at the interpretation $(\mathbb{N}, \mathcal{E}, f)$, where $f(x) = x+1$ and $\mathcal{E}$ is the equivalence relation with two classes, one consisting of the odd numbers and one consisting of the even numbers. This is a model of equality logic in which $1\mathcal{E} 3$.

Comment: Okay! Getting closer to understanding it: The size / cardinality of the domain is obviously its number of non-equal elements. But the interpretation of which elements are equal is up to us, i.e. we can freely choose the equivalence relation. In other words, we can take an arbitrary equivalence relation, and the formula $\exists^{\geq n}$ still asserts that there are at least n non-equal elements in the domain. Just with our custom equivalence relation.